# Theme not rendering

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, themes, instance

Thanks your time. I tried searching  errors  typing in wp-config.php to review the Mime Apache settings in my I EC2 AWS instance where is my WordPress

I also installed a new, clean, WordPress, in the same instance but the problem persist in the theme and in the wp login the CSS Html does not load. You can see it in url: bitcommit.ec

Comment: Could you add some more detail please, it's not clear what the error is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try loading a default theme like twenty twenty and seeing if it loads correctly. There looks like there maybe a few issues with your theme check your inspection tool.

Comment: The problem is happening due to the server sending a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` for all JS/CSS files, which are therefore not interpreted correctly. There's something wrong with the Apache configuration - no idea, never used it on AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Part of the answer was exactly the bad reading of httpd to the header server, the default one- in the instance EC2-AWS-  isn't compatible with css. Reasons: I dont know. I accidentally found the answer when I was trying to install Nginx...I had conflicts; when I resolved the first one related about the header in the server I reinstalled httpd  and it started to work. Thanks for all your help; and next time I will have more atention to the standard of writing in Stackoverflow.